# Oracle not able to insert exception into table

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, stored-procedures

I have below procedure where i am trying to track the exceptions into `I_Log` table.To test whether its working or not I have made a `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` error in my query where I am trying to insert into `I_OPTION` table. When i run this procedure the dbms output line is printing the error below but its not getting inserted into `I_Log` table:

```
OTHERS exception in EXT_I_OPTION - ID:1000196-933----ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Below is my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
  "EXT_I_OPTION"(in_id IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0)
AS
  err_code    VARCHAR(100);
  err_msg     VARCHAR(100);
  in_event_id NUMBER;
  in_db_link  VARCHAR2(50);
  in_env_id   NUMBER;
  l_sql       VARCHAR2(5000);
  l_sql1      VARCHAR2(5000);
  BEGIN        

    FOR I_row IN I_cur
    LOOP

      l_sql2 := INSERT INTO I_OPTION(ID)
                select DISTINCT(SO.ID)
                     )
                  from Icard I;                      

    END LOOP;

    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      err_code := SQLCODE;
      err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
      INSERT INTO I_log (I_ID)
      VALUES (i_id);   

      RAISE;

      COMMIT;

  END ext_I_option;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a `RAISE` before `COMMIT`; this way, the error will be raised before doing `COMMIT`, so you don't find data in your log table.

According to suggestions, you should define a procedure to handle your log table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure i_LOG (...) AS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

BEGIN
    Insert into I_LOG(...); 

    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

This procedure runs in a separate transaction, so it only does `commit` of log data, with no conflict with data you modify in your main procedure.
Then you should modify your error handling in this way, avoiding `COMMIT` statement, that can be really dangerous, saving partial, unconsistent data:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OTHERS exception in EXT_I_OPTION - ID:'||to_char(ID) || err_code || '----' || err_msg );
ins_I_LOG(...);
RAISE;
```

Comment: Exactly. Inserting into the log table should be done in a separate procedure with the `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` pragma.

Comment: thanks Aleksej its working now. @ammoQ do you have any small example of to track into log table in separate procedure with Autonomous_Trasaction and is there any disadvatnage of doing in every procedure ?

Comment: Edited the answer according to ammoQ suggestions

Comment: You have no limitations on this; I would not reply the procedure in every package, it's better keep it in a utility package, or even as a stand-alone procedure. I usually use a stand-alone procedure, but it's somehow a personal choice